# Why does my immediate window display the value but when I assign it in my loop I get a runtime error '6'?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub quintic_spline()

    Dim x(9) As Variant
    Dim y(9) As Variant
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim i As Variant
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim a As Long
    Dim b As Long
    
    
    n = 9
    For i = 0 To n
        x(i) = Cells(i + 2, 1)
        y(i) = Cells(i + 2, 2)
    Next i
    

    
    Dim p_k_inter(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As Variant
    Dim p_k(10) As Variant
    i = 0
    Dim Value As Double
    
    For a = 1 To 2
        For b = 1 To 2
            If a = 1 And b = 1 Then
                Value = 3 / 2 * ((1 / (x(i + 1) - x(i))) + (1 / (x(i + 2) - x(i + 1))))
                p_k_inter(1, 1) = Value
            ElseIf a = 1 And b = 2 Then
                p_k_inter(1, 2) = (-3) * ((1 / (x(i + 1) - x(i)) ^ 2) - (1 / (x(i + 2) - x(i + 1)) ^ 2))
            ElseIf a = 2 And b = 1 Then
                p_k_inter(2, 1) = (-3) * ((1 / (x(i + 1) - x(i)) ^ 2) - (1 / (x(i + 2) - x(i + 1)) ^ 2))
            Else
               p_k_inter(2, 2) = (8) * ((1 / (x(i + 1) - x(i)) ^ 3) + (1 / (x(i + 2) - x(i + 1)) ^ 3))
            End If
        Next b
    Next a
```

So when I typed the 'value' variable code into the immediate window, a value of 30 shows up. However, when I try to run the code in VBA, I get a runtime error '6'. What could be the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: You should paste your actual code in instead of pasting a picture...

Comment: @jamheadart have posted the code now

Comment: Your nested For loops appear to be redundant. With no idea of your data or what you did in the immediate window it's hard to know the problem.

Comment: In which line of code exactly do you get the runtime error and what is the exact error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why is `i` variant? Row counting needs to be `Long`, therefore `n` should be `Long` too and `j` is declared but never used.
2. Why have these formulas `Value = 3 / 2 * ((1 / (x(i + 1) - x(i))) + (1 / (x(i + 2) - x(i + 1))))` the variable `i` if it always `0` and does not change in the loop at all? You could write it as `Value = 3 / 2 * ((1 / (x(1) - x(0))) + (1 / (x(2) - x(1))))` same for the other formulas.
3. Your 2 loops are doing nothing. You don't need them at all and can just remove them. The result will be the same.

The following code does the same as yours:

```
Sub quintic_spline()
    Const n As Long = 9

    ReDim x(n) As Variant
    ReDim y(n) As Variant
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To n
        x(i) = Cells(i + 2, 1)  'better define the worksheet for the cells like
        y(i) = Cells(i + 2, 2)  'Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 2, 2)
    Next i
    
    Dim p_k_inter(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As Double
    p_k_inter(1, 1) = 3 / 2 * ((1 / (x(1) - x(0))) + (1 / (x(2) - x(1))))
    p_k_inter(1, 2) = -3 * ((1 / (x(1) - x(0)) ^ 2) - (1 / (x(2) - x(1)) ^ 2))
    p_k_inter(2, 1) = -3 * ((1 / (x(1) - x(0)) ^ 2) - (1 / (x(2) - x(1)) ^ 2))
    p_k_inter(2, 2) = 8 * ((1 / (x(1) - x(0)) ^ 3) + (1 / (x(2) - x(1)) ^ 3))
End Sub
```

Also since `p_k_inter(1, 2)` and `p_k_inter(2, 1)` use the same formula you could write `p_k_inter(2, 1) = p_k_inter(1, 2)` instead of calculating the formula again.

Finally I don't understand why you read `n=9` values for `x()` and `y()` but you only use `n=3` values from `x()` and `y()` is never used. Looks like you can limit `n` to `3` and kick out `y(i) = Cells(i + 2, 2)`. The result would still be the same but faster.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for the response. The reason I had i=0 is because right now am trying to create only one matrix but I want to create for matrices for my data in the future and will loop through the data. 

Unfortunately, I am still getting a runtime '6' error using your code :/

Comment: @travybel well, ok in that case keep the `i` but still the loops are not necessary. Which line is the error? And what are the values of `x(0)` and `x(1)` and `x(2)`?

Comment: Nevermind, I tried on my PC and it seems to be working (was trying on my Mac before). Not really sure why changing to my PC worked but oh well. Thanks! 

Yeah, I'll keep the `i` and removed the loops.